# ¿Por qué php no me retorna el JSON normal, cuando lo envío a javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Al llamar esta función en 'javascript':

```
function mostrar(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var txt = "";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var array = this.responseText;
            console.log(this.status);
            console.log(array);
            console.log(this.responseText);
            for (x in array) {
                txt += array[x].mensaje + " - " + array[x].fecha_mensaje + "<br/>";
            }
            document.getElementById("recibido").innerHTML = txt;
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/redsocial/mensajes/getMessagesReceived/2/3",true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Para que me retorne el valor de esta función que retorna un array normal:

```
public function getMessagesReceived($emisor,$receptor)
    {
        $data = $this->mensaje->getMessagesReceived($emisor,$receptor);
        $datos = [
            'mensaje' => $data->mensaje,
            'fecha_mensaje' => $data->fecha_mensaje
        ];
        var_dump(json_encode($datos));
        $var = json_encode($datos);
        return $var;
    }
```

El problema es que cuando hago el `var_dump()` en php me retorna bien el array convertido a JSON, pero cuando hago debug en javascript me muestra esto:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\xampp\htdocs\redsocial\app\controllers\Mensajes.php:82:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'{&quot;mensaje&quot;:&quot;Hola&quot;,&quot;fecha_mensaje&quot;:&quot;2020-01-17 00:34:58&quot;}'</font> <i>(length=56)</i>
</pre>
```

Comment: Yo probaría a hacer en JavaScript: array = JSON.parse(array);

Comment: En php no existe JSON.stringify ni JSOn.parse, ya que son funciones de JavaScript

Comment: Tienes que quitar esta línea: `var_dump(json_encode($datos));` pues esa salida saldría mezclada con el JSON y en Javascript tendrías por tanto un JSON inválido. Solamente debes emitir el JSON, nada más.

Comment: como dice @A.Cedano si quitas el `var_dump();` funcionará, ya que esta función te agrega no solo el contenido entre comillas sino que además al inicio pondría algo como esto: **string(249)** con lo cual la estructura esperada se *rompe*

Comment: Ya lo hice y si recibi el array en javascript, pero ahora no me quiere recorrer ahora recibo este tipo de array: [{"mensaje":"Hola","fecha_mensaje":"2020-01-17 00:34:58"},{"mensaje":"Hola","fecha_mensaje":"2020-01-17 00:35:36"},{"mensaje":"q","fecha_mensaje":"2020-01-17 00:39:57"}]

Comment: Ya vi y me lo guarda como 1 solo array cuando yo los necesito separados

Comment: Si lo que quieres es un JSON, interpréta el texto recibido: `var array = JSON.parse(this.responseText);`

Comment: @JoanSebastianOviedo tu funcion getMessagesReceived retorna un valor y este como lo envias ? si no lo envias  solo ejecutas la funcion en vez de   $var = json_encode($datos); usa echo json_encode($datos); y quita el var_dump